# Importing product images from URL problem

Tags: product-images, magento2.3, product-import

I'm trying to import some products from a csv with images that are stored on an external server. The images are saving to the var/import folder ok but they won't assign to the product. I'm using the google logo to test. 
The `exception.log` file says:
`main.CRITICAL: File 'var/import/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.pnggooglelogo_color_272x92dp.png' was not found or has read restriction. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): File 'var/import/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.pnggooglelogo_color_272x92dp.png' was not found or has read restriction. at /home/account/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Uploader.php:210)"} []`
See how it's concatenating the file name twice? What's going on?
The import works fine if I use a local path but goes screwy when I put an external url in the source.
For the record the image source is:
`https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`

I've tried the same file on a different installation of 2.3 and got the same result. The same file worked perfectly on 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

I overwrote /vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Uploader.php with the version from 2.2.6 and it worked fine.

Comment: You should not overwrite files in vendor folders directly. Did you write a patch for it, can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

I compared both files Magento 2.X and Magento 2.3 and got the issue related to this.

Please open this file /vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Uploader.php
There is missing one condition in function setTmpDir() and here is the missing code with line by line

1. missing to use

   use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager; http://prntscr.com/mfvnv8 on line no : 10
2. missing code on line no 99 to 102

   /**

   - @var \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver
     */
     private $directoryResolver;
3. missing code on line no 135 
   $this->directoryResolver = $directoryResolver
           ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver::class);
4. missing code on line no 112

   - @param \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver|null $directoryResolver
5. missing to add code in __construct()
   \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver $directoryResolver = null
6. missing code on line no 134
   $this->directoryResolver = $directoryResolver
           ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver::class);
7. Missing code in line no 294

   Old code 
   public function setTmpDir($path)
   {
       if (is_string($path) && $this->_directory->isReadable($path)) {
           $this->_tmpDir = $path;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   - Replace it with below code

   public function setTmpDir($path)
   {
       if (is_string($path)
           && $this->_directory->isReadable($path)
           && $this->directoryResolver->validatePath($this->_directory->getAbsolutePath($path), DirectoryList::ROOT)
       ) {
           $this->_tmpDir = $path;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

Hope, This one is useful to understand you why this is not uploading.

Thank you